# Adding to object in list ends up adding to all list objects

Tags: python, reference, dijkstra

I'm new in Python and I want to make Dijkstra's algorithm and I'm having problem in the very beginning.

I have objects for vertices and edges:

```
class Vertex:
minDistance = float('inf')
previousVertex = None
edges = []
id = None
name = None

def __init__(self, id, name):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name


class Edge:
source = None
target = None
weight = None

def __init__(self, source, target, weight):
    self.source = source
    self.target = target
    self.weight = weight
```

I want to take a vertex and to his property *edges* add every edge that starts in it. Do this for every vertex I have:

```
vertices = []    

def createGraph(self, vertices, edgesToVertices):
    self.vertices = vertices[:]
    for x in vertices:
        for edge in edgesToVertices:
            if edge.source is x.id:
                x.edges.append(edge)
```

The problem is when I append the on the last line, the edge is added to ALL vertices in the list. 
Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong and why?

Comment: You should use `==` not `is` to test equality.  I doubt that's the source of your problem though

Comment: remove the three lines immediately below `class Edge:`.  If you want to have default attributes, have them as default arguments to `__init__`

Comment: The same for `Vertex`.  I think the problem is that all your vertices share one list `edges`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list, `edges`, that you defined in `Vertex` is a class variable.  So, if you modify it, it affects all `Vertex` instances (hence the behavior that you're describing).

What you can do is:

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.edges = []
        self.previousVertex = None
        self.minDistance = float('inf')

class Edge:
    def __init__(self, source, target, weight):
        self.source = source
        self.target = target
        self.weight = weight
```

This way, `edges` belongs to each instance.

By the way, I'm guessing that you intend `createGraph()` to be part of `Edge`.  If that were the case, you could implement it like the following:

```
class Edge:
    def __init__(self, source, target, weight):
        self.source = source
        self.target = target
        self.weight = weight

    def createGraph(self, vertices, edgesToVertices):
        for vertex in vertices:
            for edge in edgesToVertices:
                if edge.source is vertex.id:
                    vertex.edges.append(edge)
```

Comment: Ok I see it now. Had no idea the Python objects worked like this. Thank you very much!